# Creating backup of Report to a specific location using SAP BO SDK

Tags: c#, .net, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am trying to backup the reports using SAP BO SDK in C#, but i am not able to figure out as to how to specify a location on disk.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the source location or the target location?  Which API are you using or is it home grown?  The question is vague on what you are doing, or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, so my response will be somewhat generic.

If you are trying to copy a report in CMS to a different CMS folder, all you need to do is create a copy of the underlying infoObject, and set its parent_id to the id of the destination CMS folder (Alternatively, change the name of your copy). The location on disk is all managed by the input file server, so you don't need to worry about it.

If you need to backup the report somewhere on the server, you'll need to get a hook to the content stream and write it to a file as you would with any other stream. In this case, you are responsible for providing a file location and name.